# Encontrar camino más corto entre dos nodos

Tags: python, nodos

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que consiste en encontrar el camino más corto entre dos nodos de un grafo indirecto y sin costes.

Dicho camino tiene que pasar por unos nodos específicos entre medias.
Lo que hago es, encontrar el camino entre el comienzo y los nodos intermedios con el código de más abajo, luego el camino entre los nodos intermedios en si, y luego el camino entre nodos intermedios y el final. Y las minimas distancias de cada uno son las que sumo al final para encontrar el camino más corto.
Es decir, cada camino debe contener: el nodo inicio, uno de los nodos de examination[0], uno de los nodos de examination[[1](https://notepin.co/shared/ttohdoz)] y el nodo final.

He seguido el algoritmo de BFS y el programa en si funciona, pero debo hacer que funcione más rápido y no encuentro la manera de agilizarlo. Este es mi código de BFS. Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
import queue
import csv
from typing import TextIO
from time import time


class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.adyacentes = []
        self.id = id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other == self.id
        elif isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return other.id == self.id


class Grafo:
    def __init__(self, num_nodos): 
        self.tamano = num_nodos
        self.nodos = []
        for id in range(num_nodos):
            self.nodos.append(Nodo(id))

    def anadir_camino(self, nodo_1, nodo_2):
        nodo1 = self.nodos[nodo_1]
        nodo2 = self.nodos[nodo_2]
        nodo1.adyacentes.append(nodo2)
        nodo2.adyacentes.append(nodo1)


def buscar_camino(grafo, minimo, maximo):
    explorado = []

    cola = [[grafo.nodos[minimo]]]

    while cola:
        camino = cola.pop(0)
        nodo = camino[-1]

        if nodo not in explorado:
            for adyacente in nodo.adyacentes:
                nuevo_camino = list(camino)
                nuevo_camino.append(adyacente)
                cola.append(nuevo_camino)

                if adyacente == maximo:
                    return len(nuevo_camino)
            explorado.append(nodo)


archivo = open("archivo.txt", "r")
fichero = archivo.readlines()

prilinea = list(fichero[0].split())

cities = int(prilinea.pop(0))
roads = int(prilinea.pop(0))
start = int(prilinea.pop(0))
target = int(prilinea.pop(0))

grafo = Grafo(cities)
lineas = []
i = 1

while i <= roads:
    lineas.append(fichero[i].split())
    i += 1

examination=[]
examination.insert(0, fichero[-2].split())
examination.insert(1, fichero[-1].split())

i = 0
while i < roads:
    grafo.anadir_camino(int(lineas[i].pop(0)), int(lineas[i].pop(0)))
    i += 1

camino = []

minimo = 999999
comienzo = 0
examinado = 0
j = 0

for i in range(2):
    for valor in examination[i]:
        min = buscar_camino(grafo, start, int(valor))
        if min < minimo:
            minimo = min
            comienzo = int(valor)
            examinado = i

if examinado == 0:
    j = 1

minimo2 = 9999999

for valor in examination[j]:
    min = buscar_camino(grafo, comienzo, int(valor))
    if min < minimo2:
        minimo2 = min
        start = int(valor)

distancia = buscar_camino(grafo, start, target)

resultado = minimo + minimo2 + distancia - 2

print(resultado)

#deberia 208
```

Los datos de "archivo.txt" se encuentran en este [enlace](https://notepin.co/shared/ttohdoz)

Comment: La variable `examination` no está definida. Revisa y edita tu código.

Comment: Si está definida, únicamente no he puesto el código completo. En examination[0] se guardan todos los nodos de un tipo de los cuales el camino tiene que visitar mínimo uno, y en examination[1] lo mismo, se guardan los nodos de otro tipo de los cuales tiene que visitar mínimo uno.

Comment: El camino debe de componerse de: inicio, 1 nodo de examination[0], 1 nodo de examination[1] y el final

Comment: @CandidMoe perdona, soy nueva y no lo sabía. Ya la he actualizado.

Answer (score 0):

Aplique perfilamiento al código y obtuve lo siguiente:

```
         348976877 function calls in 58.687 seconds


   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
116255042   33.223    0.000   46.182    0.000 scratch_3.py:12(__eq__)
     9850    0.005    0.000    0.006    0.000 scratch_3.py:25(anadir_camino)
     5000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 scratch_3.py:8(__init__)
232450842   12.959    0.000   12.959    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
    78215    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
     9853    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
```

Lo que nos señala al método `__eq__` de la clase `Nodo` como el culpable:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, int):
        return other == self.id
    elif isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return other.id == self.id
```

Veamos como reemplazar este método por algo más simple.

El método `__eq__` se utiliza en dos partes dentro de la función `buscar_camino`:

```
    if nodo not in explorado:
        for adyacente in nodo.adyacentes:
            nuevo_camino = list(camino)
            nuevo_camino.append(adyacente)
            cola.append(nuevo_camino)

            if adyacente == maximo:
                return len(nuevo_camino)
```

Se usa en `if nodo not in explorado` y en `if adyacente == maximo`.

En el último caso, `adyacente` será siempre un `Nodo` y `maximo` será siempre un entero. Puedo evitar la llamada a `__eq__` haciendo directamente la comparación:

```
            if adyacente.id == maximo:
                return len(nuevo_camino)
```

El primer `if` puede ser más económico si en lugar de buscar dentro de una lista de nodos, busco dentro de una lista de enteros. Para eso creare un arreglo paralelo a `explorado`, contiendo sólo los `id` de los nodos. Este arreglo lo nombro `ids`.

La función queda entonces así:

```
def buscar_camino(grafo, minimo, maximo):
    explorado = []
    ids = []

    cola = [[grafo.nodos[minimo]]]

    while cola:
        camino = cola.pop(0)
        nodo = camino[-1]

        if nodo.id not in ids:
            for adyacente in nodo.adyacentes:
                nuevo_camino = list(camino)
                nuevo_camino.append(adyacente)
                cola.append(nuevo_camino)

                if adyacente.id == maximo:
                    return len(nuevo_camino)
            explorado.append(nodo)
            ids.append(nodo.id)
```

Con esto también puede eliminar el método `__eq__`, ya que no lo usaremos más.

Ejecutando, obtenemos este resultado:

```
     285986 function calls in 1.144 seconds
```

Pasamos de 58 segundos a 1 segundo de tiempo de ejecución.

Nota: En ambos casos el programa retorna el valor 228, lo que significa que la refactorización no afecta la lógica del código.

Comment: es un punto de vista muy interesante, no se me había ocurrido muchas gracias. Aún así, el programa sigue siendo muy lento con ejemplos en los que hay mayor cantidad de nodos, debido a que el algoritmo BFS empleado en buscar_camino ocupa mucho tiempo con la cola con caminos innecesarios. Sería posible algún otro tipo de enfoque de búsqueda de nodos en este tipo de grafos?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es dividir el grafo manualmente y resolver cada parte por separado, si el grafo en particular se presta para eso. No se; está fuera de mi área.